# Dynamically query entity framework with linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need a function to get a key-value pair of `Id` and `Description` from a entity model for populating some fields on a user control and I'd like to find a way to make it dynamic in order to avoid repeating code.

My pseudo-code:

```
public List<object> GetData(string modelName, string modelId, string modelDescription)
{
    using(DbEntities context = new DbEntities())
    {
        return (from d in context.modelName
                select new { 
                            id=d.modelId,
                            description = d.modelDescription
                           }
               ).ToList<object>();
    }
}
```

A possible partial solution could be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26359631/1538384), but the table needs to be dynamically defined too.

Comment: You'd like to find a way to make it generic :-)

Comment: what's the input of your modelName??

Comment: your question is the [same as this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15925091/2374987

Comment: @FerasSalim a string which is the name of an entity framework object, like "Users" or "Customers"

Comment: @Doc see this  stackoverflow.com/q/15925091/2374987

Answer (score 0):

In you context you have something similar to

```
public DbSet<MyEntity> ThePropertyName {get; set;}
```

when you call you function modelName = "ThePropertyName"

So you could retrieve the DbSet via reflection then run a ToList on it. Then you could use a foreach on the entities and via reflection you could retrieve the properties modelId and modelDescription.